# Add more cells UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, uicollectionview

Well right now I am replacing my images from Instagram by getting to the bottom of the screen rather than adding new cells. How would I add new cells rather than replacing previous ones?

**Here is my total implemantation file to retrieve the next page of images:**

```
@interface StreamViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *timelineResponse;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CredentialStore *credentialStore;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;

@end

@implementation StreamViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self refreshInstagram];

    //Refresh
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(startRefresh:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.collectionView addSubview:refreshControl];

    //Instigate Navigation Bar Buttons
    UIButton *barButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [barButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [barButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"barButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [barButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"barButton_s.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [barButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapBarButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    barButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 30.0f, 30.0f);
    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:barButton];

    self.navBar.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;

    UIButton *postButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [postButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [postButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pen_usIMG.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [postButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pen_sIMG.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [postButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapPostButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    postButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 30.0f, 30.0f);
    UIBarButtonItem *postButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:postButton];

    self.navBar.rightBarButtonItem = postButtonItem;

    //Reload by default
    [self.collectionView reloadData];

}


//Global refresh Instagram Method
- (void)refreshInstagram {

    [[InstagramClient sharedClient] getPath:@"users/self/feed"
                                 parameters:nil
                                    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                        NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
                                        self.timelineResponse = responseObject;
                                        [self.collectionView reloadData];

                                    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                        NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
                                    }];

}

- (void)nextInstagramPage:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSDictionary *page = self.timelineResponse[@"pagination"];
    NSString *nextPage = page[@"next_url"];

    [[InstagramClient sharedClient] getPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",nextPage] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        self.timelineResponse = [responseObject mutableCopy];
        [self.timelineResponse addEntriesFromDictionary:responseObject];
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
    }];



}
- (NSMutableArray *)entries {
    return self.timelineResponse[@"data"];
}

- (NSArray *)pages {
    return self.timelineResponse[@"pagination"];
}


- (NSURL *)imageUrlForEntryAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSDictionary *entry = [self entries][indexPath.row];
    NSString *imageUrlString = entry[@"images"][@"standard_resolution"][@"url"];
    return [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString];
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDelegate

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //int y = arc4random() % 200+50;


    return CGSizeMake(150, 150);


}
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    RNBlurModalView *modal = [[RNBlurModalView alloc] initWithViewController:self title:@"Item Tapped!" message:@"Thank God its working"];
    [modal show];
}


- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y == roundf(scrollView.contentSize.height-scrollView.frame.size.height)) {
        NSLog(@"we are at the endddd");
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

        [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
            [self nextInstagramPage:indexPath];

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {


        }
         ];
    }
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [[self entries] count];

}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ( indexPath.item == ([[self entries] count] - 1) ) {
        // download more data and add it to the 'entries' array
        [self refreshInstagram];


    }

    ImageCell *cell = (ImageCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"imageCell"
                                                                             forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSURL *url = [self imageUrlForEntryAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"%@", url);
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

#pragma mark - NavigationBarButtons

- (void)didTapBarButton:(id)sender {

    [self.sidePanelController showLeftPanelAnimated:YES];

}

- (void)startRefresh:(UIRefreshControl *)sender {
    [self refreshInstagram];
    [sender endRefreshing];

}

-(void)didTapPostButton:(id)sender {


}

@end
```

**Here is a way to add new cells:**

```
-(void)addNewCells {
    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        int resultsSize = [[self entries]count];
        [self.results addObjectsFromArray:newData];
        NSMutableArray *arrayWithIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i = resultsSize; i < resultsSize + newData.count; i++)
            [arrayWithIndexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
    }
     [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:arrayWithIndexPaths];
     }
                                  completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried updating the return value of `collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section` ? and (correspondingly) adding more images to the array (or whatever container) where you keep your images?

Comment: I made it the amount of images in the array

Comment: As far as I know, if, when the user scrolls to the bottom, you grab more images and add them to your array (so that it now has older and newer images), then call `reloadData` (and numberOfItemsInSection now returns [yourArray count]), it should do what you want.

Comment: Where should I put reloadData

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to keep an *array* of the photos that are returned from the service. The dictionary won't work, as Mundi's answer suggests, because *adding* the responses from the dictionary is going to *replace* existing key/value pairs. That's why you're seeing the flashing.

Add an `NSMutableArray` property to your view controller and add entries from the data to it.

```
[self.photosArray addObjectsFromArray:responseObject[@"data"]];
```

And then user `self.photosArray` in your `entries` method.

Answer (score 2):

You simply increase your data array. Make `timelineResponse` into a `NSMutableArray` and

<strike>[self.timelineResponse addObjectsFromArray:responseObject];</strike>

```
[self.timelineResponse addEntriesFromDictionary:responseObject];
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

Comment: Currently timelineResponse is a NSDictionary could i do the same without changing it to be a nsmutable array. I added my whole .m file above for reference

Comment: Well, you get the idea :)

Comment: wait i dont get it do i or do i not change it from a dictionary to an array

Comment: Whatever you are using, make it mutable. In your declaration it is a `NSDictionary` so make it into `NSMutableDictionary` and use `addEntriesFromDictionary` to expand it.

Comment: I get this error for that: 2013-07-27 11:42:57.141 Floadt[4877:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2fc5012 0x25f6e7e 0x2fc4deb 0x2f8b347 0x2faaa9b 0x60e46 0x36049 0x276953f 0x277b014 0x276b7d5 0x2f6baf5 0x2f6af44 0x2f6ae1b 0x2ba27e3 0x2ba2668 0x1763ffc 0x2d6d 0x2c95)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

Comment: - (void)nextInstagramPage:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSDictionary *page = self.timelineResponse[@"pagination"];
    NSString *nextPage = page[@"next_url"];
    
    [[InstagramClient sharedClient] getPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",nextPage] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id json) {
        [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self.timelineResponse addEntriesFromDictionary:json];      [self.collectionView reloadData];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
    }];
}

Comment: You'll need to replace the `self.timelineResponse = responseObject;` with `self.timelineResponse = [responseObject mutableCopy];` in order to get a mutable variant.

Comment: @AshFurrow I just tried it however it just flickers between the old and new pictures